# Complex Automapper Configuration

Tags: automapper, automapper-4

I'm mapping from an existing database to a DTO and back again use Automapper (4.1.1) and I've hit a few small problems.

I have a (simplified) model for the database table:

```
public class USER_DETAILS
{
    [Key]
    public string UDT_LOGIN { get; set; }
    public string UDT_USER_NAME { get; set; }
    public string UDT_INITIALS { get; set; }
    public string UDT_USER_GROUP { get; set; }
    public decimal UDT_CLAIM_LIMIT { get; set; }
    public string UDT_CLAIM_CCY { get; set; }
}
```

and a DTO object:

```
public class User
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string UserGroup { get; set; }
    public double ClaimLimit { get; set; }
    public string ClaimCurrency { get; set; }
}
```

I've created a profile

```
public class FromProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        this.RecognizePrefixes("UDT_");
        this.ReplaceMemberName("CCY", "Currency");
        this.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new UpperUnderscoreNamingConvention();
        this.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
        this.CreateMap<decimal, double>().ConvertUsing((decimal src) => (double)src);

        this.CreateMap<USER_DETAILS, User>();
    }
}
```

However, it seems that Automapper doesn't like combining this many settings in the config. Even simplifying the models, I can't get

```
        this.RecognizePrefixes("UDT_");
        this.ReplaceMemberName("CCY", "Currency");
```

to work together, and whilst

```
        this.CreateMap<decimal, double>().ConvertUsing((decimal src) => (double)src);
```

works ok with the models in the test, it fails when using it against a database.

Is there a way to get all this to work together, or should I fall back to using **ForMember()**. I was really hoping I could get this working as there are a **lot** of tables in this system, and I'd rather not have to do each one individually.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to extend this for other types, only tested with strings, I have an extension method that does all the work and looks for unmapped properties.

```
public class USER_DETAILS
{
    public string UDT_LOGIN { get; set; }
    public string UDT_USER_NAME { get; set; }
    public string UDT_INITIALS { get; set; }
    public string UDT_USER_GROUP { get; set; }
   // public decimal UDT_CLAIM_LIMIT { get; set; }
    public string UDT_CLAIM_CCY { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string UserGroup { get; set; }
    //public double ClaimLimit { get; set; }
    public string ClaimCurrency { get; set; }
}

public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination>
        CustomPropertyMapper<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
    {
        var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
        var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);
        var existingMaps = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().First(x => x.SourceType == sourceType && x.DestinationType == destinationType);

        var properties = sourceType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in existingMaps.GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
        {
            var similarPropertyName =
                properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Replace("_", "").Replace("UDT", "").ToLower().Contains(property.ToLower()));

            if(similarPropertyName == null)
                continue;

            var myPropInfo = sourceType.GetProperty(similarPropertyName.Name);
            expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.MapFrom<string>(myPropInfo.Name));
        }
        return expression;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeAutomapper();

        var userDetails = new USER_DETAILS
        {
            UDT_LOGIN = "Labi-Login",
            UDT_USER_NAME = "Labi-UserName",
            UDT_INITIALS = "L"
        };

        var mapped = Mapper.Map<User>(userDetails);
    }

    static void InitializeAutomapper()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<USER_DETAILS, User>().CustomPropertyMapper();
    }
}
```

}